# Attach Function to onClick()/onPress()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `Component` looking like this:

```
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

_onPress = (key) => {
    alert(key);
  }

_createList = () => {
     const list = Object.keys(this.state.obj).map((key, index) => {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          key = {index}
          style = {style.container}
          onPress = {this._onPress(key)}
          >
          <Text>{key}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
       )
     });
      return list;
   }

  render() {
    const listview = this._createList();
    return (
      <View>
        {listview}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Ob Startup I get three `alerts` (one for each key/value pair in my Object). That behaviour is expected. However, when I click on one of the `Texts/Touchables`, I do not get an `alert`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
onPress = { () => this._onPress(key) }
```

with `onPress = {this._onPress(key)}`, onPress bind to the result of `_onPress` function call, that equal to undefined.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the callback, not the callback result.

`onPress = {event => this._onPress(key)}`